# pytorch profiler explanation of layers

Tags: pytorch, profiler

I am using the [pytorch profiler](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html) api but i am having difficulty understanding the output. Here in the figure what does the `Name` column mean? I understand it shows the model layers but what is `aten:gru`,`aten:uniform` etc. Also I want the output to be like that of [torchprof](https://github.com/awwong1/torchprof) where i can see how much time each feature is taking (a more detailed breakdown). What's the equivalent of `prof.display(show_events=True)` in pytorch profiler?

[image: profiler output]